# Mongoexport not working with IPv6 address

Tags: mongodb, ipv6, mongoexport

I recently started working on MongoDB and facing some issues with the mongoexport utility.

Mongoexport works well when connecting to remote host using IPv4, but gives error when using IPv6.

MongoDB Version is 3.2

```
C:\Users\Shruti>ping NISHAD-PC

Pinging NISHAD-PC [fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12: time=3ms
Reply from fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12: time=3ms
Reply from fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12: time=3ms
Reply from fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12: time=3ms

Ping statistics for fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 3ms

C:\Users\Shruti>ping -4 NISHAD-PC

Pinging NISHAD-PC [192.168.0.101] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.101: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.101: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.101: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.101: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.101:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 3ms

C:\Users\Shruti>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongoexport" /h 192.168.0.101  /d db /c Employee /f "empid,name" /type:csv /o "C:\DBData\Employee_v4.csv"
2016-10-30T15:04:10.784+0530    connected to: 192.168.0.101
2016-10-30T15:04:10.789+0530    exported 7 records


C:\Users\Shruti>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongoexport" /h [fe80::68cc:168e:171c:ed90%12] /d db /c Employee /f "empid,name" /type:csv /o "C:\DBData\Employee_v6.csv"
2016-10-30T15:03:58.073+0530    error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please avoid useless text (see what I deleted).

Comment: Are you sure that you need to surround the IPv6 address with brackets? That is required for a URL, but not for other things.

Comment: Yes. It is mentioned in the  [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) 
Changed in version 3.0.0: If you use IPv6 and use the <address>:<port> format, you must enclose the portion of an address and port combination in brackets (e.g. [<address>]).